# How do I change scenes in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Let's say I have game levels: `level_1.scn`, `level_2.scn`, `level_3.scn` and so on. What's the best way to go from the current level to the next level if the player has completed the level?

Here's what I tried:

```swift
extension GameViewController: SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEnd contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        guard let nodeA = contact.nodeA.name else { return }
        guard let nodeB = contact.nodeB.name else { return }

        if nodeA == "player" && nodeB == "finishLine" || nodeA == "finishLine" && nodeB == "player" {
            if let scene = SCNScene(named: "scenes.scnassets/level_2.scn") {
                sceneView.present(scene, with: .fade(withDuration: 0.25), incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once this part of the code is executed, the scene is changed, **but with a significant delay**. My levels are pretty simple and I don't think they should be loaded for more than 1 second. And after the scene changes, I lose the ability to control the player.

Looks like I'm doing something wrong. Because the console displays a warning:

> Scene  is modified within a rendering callback
>   of another scene (). This is not allowed and
>   may lead to a crash.

How to create the correct logic for changing scenes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the delay is caused by calling `sceneView.present` multiple times. `func physicsWorld` will run multiple times while conditions are met and that may cause the delay you mentioned. Try using a variable to prevent such thing from happening.